# Change Texblock style when another Texblock value change

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I'm trying to change the style of another textblock when certain textblock is changed.  I'm trying to use datatrigger.  Is this the right way?  and here is my code.

```
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Name="txtChangeTo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="48" Text="2">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=txtChange, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Value="">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="red"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
    <Button x:Name="btnChangeValue" Content="Change Value" Click="btnChangeValue_Click"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, this seems good to me except the textbox you are binding to is missing. So the First line should be something like `<TextBox x:Name="txtChange"/>`.
Also in your example, the style is applied when the textblock text is empty so you won't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, but I would suggest you to use MVVM so the styling is determined by the ViewModel and not the View as it does right now. The first TextBlock should change a property in the ViewModel and the second should determine it's state based on the ViewModel state. Referencing other controls in the way you do it make the code really fragile.